# Formatting dependent parameters in Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, python-toolbox

I am setting up my parameters for my tool in python toolbox. So far it looks like this:

[image]

The user inputs a tif into the Input Raster. I want the Select Bands (optional) tab to be a drop down menu that includes all of the bands contained in the .tif in the Input Raster. What changes do I need to make to my code (included below) to make this happen? I do not want to use the script wizard available in arcmap.  This has to be done in Python Toolbox only.

```
import arcpy,os,sys

class Toolbox(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.label =  "Exploding Rasters"
    self.alias  = "ER"

    # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
    self.tools = [ExplodeRasters] 

class ExplodeRasters(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self.label       = "Explode Rasters"
    self.description = " This tool will take an input multiband raster and extract its individual bands.  "

def getParameterInfo(self):

# Input Features parameter
in_features = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Input Raster",
    name="in_features",
    datatype="DEFeatureClass",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")

# create select all bands button
all_bands = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Select all bands",
    name="Select_All",
    datatype="Boolean",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")             
TIFF = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="TIFF",
    name ="TIFF",
    datatype="Boolean",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input")
JPG = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="JPG",
    name="JPG",
    datatype="Boolean",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input")
IMG = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="IMG",
    name="IMG",
    datatype="Boolean",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input") 

# Range of Desired Bands parameter
select_bands = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Select Bands",
    name="Select_Bands",
    datatype="DEFeatureClass",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input")

select_bands.parameterDependencies = [in_features.name]
select_bands.schema.clone = True

#select bands for NDVI band parameters
NDVI_red= arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Select a red band for NDVI calculation",
    name="NDVI_bRed",
    datatype="DERasterDataset",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input")

NDVI_NIR= arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Select a NIR band for NDVI calculation",
    name="NDVI_BNIR",
    datatype="DERasterDataset",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input")

#out directory
OutDir=arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Output Workspace",
    name="Out_Directory",
    datatype="DEWorkspace",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")

# Create filename output prefix
prefix = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Output filename prefix",
    name="output_prefix",
    datatype="String",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")

parameters = [in_features, all_bands, select_bands, NDVI_red, NDVI_NIR, prefix, OutDir, TIFF, JPG, IMG]

return parameters

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    Out_Dir=parameters[6].valueAsText
    in_raster=parameters[0].valueAsText
    out_prefix=parameters[5].valueAsText

messages.addMessage("INPUT RASTER=" +in_raster)
messages.addMessage("Yay, you're doing great!")

#individual bands within multiband rasters already exist, so overwrite

arcpy.env.workspace=in_raster
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 

# get a list of the bands that make up the raster
bRng = arcpy.ListRasters()

# loop through the bands and export each one with CopyRaster
for ThisBnd in bRng:
    InBand  = ThisBnd
    bndDesc = arcpy.Describe(InBand)
    NoData  = bndDesc.noDataValue

    outRaster = os.path.join(Out_Dir, out_prefix + ThisBnd+".tif")

    #copy single band rasters
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(InBand,outRaster, format = "TIFF", nodata_value = NoData)
return
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this site isn't meant to be used as a place to get someone to do your homework for you.  If you'd like an answer, please share what you have tried so far, and why it wasn't successful.  Duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264771/how-to-auto-populate-arc-python-toolbox-drop-down-with-bands

Comment: Pardon me, I thought stack exchange was a place to ask questions.  All the code you see before you is what I have written and tried.  The included image is what I have done thus far.  I detail the next step which I am struggling with, customizing my parameters, in the premise to the question.   You are clever, the link you attached is my group member's question.  We are not trying to "pull the wool over your eyes", we are asking for advice and help on the next step of a very very long project.... on the website explicitly for this purpose.

Comment: For anyone else who still thinks this is an interesting puzzle to solve, let me try to be as specific as a confused person can be.    When you are creating a tool to run a script in ArcMap there are two ways to do it 1) use script wizard or 2) create a custom python toolbox, which is what I am doing.  To do this, you must create objects and classes to establish your parameters then connect the parameters to the script ... so the parameters are the inputs and outputs of your script.  I need my multiraster parameter "in_features" send its individual rasters to a drop down menu in "select_bands"

Comment: I have been playing with parameterDependencies, to try to take the inputs from "in_features" and clone them to my parameter "select_bands".  Errors have included "The attribute 'schema' is not supported on this instance of Parameter."  However after reading about parameter datatypes, I thought that raster datatypes created their own schema objects and therefore would need to have a schema attribute.

Comment: so after a preamble, my question is... why do the following two lines of code not allow me to clone my parameter "select_bands.parameterDependencies = [in_features.name]
select_bands.schema.clone = True"

Comment: Excellent followup comments which show the research and effort you've already put into the project.  This demonstrates to readers where you are having issues and where you need help, not just asking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: You should add the follow-up clarifications to the question itself.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/47722551/820534

Comment: @Worcester_Student please **[edit]** your question to include any information in response to comments.  Comments are intended for potential answerers to request clarification and/or more information, your response should be as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, it looks like the root of your problem may lie in the very first input parameter... "Input Raster".  You've defined the data type as a "DEFeatureClass", but that can only be used for vector data, not raster data.

Instead, try changing the data type to one of the raster types, defined in the help link below.  I would start off with either "DERasterDataset" or "GPRasterLayer".  Finally, for the "select_bands" class, I think you might be looking for the "DERasterBand" data type.

See [Defining parameter data types in a Python toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm) for more detail on the types of parameters that are available in a Python toolbox.